# gdb doesn't display parameter info

Tags: gdb, debug-symbols

I compiled my binaries using -g and tried to debug using gdb. I am able to debug it, but it does not show parameter values. I tried all configuration option to display parameter, it didn't help. Please let me know if I miss anything. Let me paste the command output

```
<code>
root> gdb /os/libexec/libmgr
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
This GDB was configured as "i386-linux".
Reading symbols from /os/libexec/libmgr...done.
(gdb) attach 2685
Attaching to program: /os/libexec/libmgr, process 2685
Reading symbols from /os/lib/libts.so.1.0...done.
................

0x74890047 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) bt
\#0  0x74890047 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
\#1  0x0817774b in thread_fetch ()
\#2  0x0809b528 in libmLocalMain ()
\#3  0x0809b6bb in main ()
(gdb) 
</code>
```

Comment: This usually turns out to be an error specifying `-g` somehow; e.g., forgetting to relink or something like that.  Can you use `readelf -WS` to make sure that `/os/libexec/libmgr` has the various .debug_* sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ported gdb 7.8. The problem is solved without changing single line of code.